# How do I draw 49 rectangles with nested loops with javafx?

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, nested-loops, rectangles

I have to use a double array to make 49 squares. What I have only given me one rectangle.

```
Rectangle[][] rectArray = new Rectangle[7][7];
//grid is a GridPane containing 49 rectangles.
GridPane grid = new GridPane();
//---- add 49 rectangles to the grid pane, it is recommended to use nested loops
for(int i = 0; i < rectArray.length; i++)
{

    for(int j = 0; j < rectArray.length; j++)
    {
        rectArray[i][j] = new Rectangle(470/7,390/7);
        rectArray[i][j].setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        rectArray[i][j].setFill(Color.WHITE);
        grid.getChildren().add(rectArray[i][j]);
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
GridPane.setConstraints(rectArray[i][j], i, j);
```

right before you add the rectangle to the grid. Right now all the rectangles are put at the same position (0, 0), so they overlap and look like one.

Comment: Another option is to use [`grid.add(rectArray[i][j], i, j)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#add(javafx.scene.Node,int,int)).